# Not getting expected output for N-Queens Problem

Tags: c++, backtracking, n-queens

I am coding the infamous N-Queens problem. But I have got a problem. The program is executing but ain't giving output as expected as I have encountered a problem as the matrix `board` values are not changed and are having the very first values assigned to `board` i.e, `0` assigned to each and every element of `board`. What could be the logical error?

Here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int board[4][4];
int isAttacked(int i, int j){
    for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
        if(board[i][k] == 1 || board[k][j] == 1) return true; // checking for the rows and columns 
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
        for(int l = 0; l < 4; l++){
            if(((k + l) == (i + j))|| ((k - l) == (i - j))){   // checking for the diagonals 
                if(board[k][l] == 1) return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
int nQueen(int N){
    if(N == 0) return true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if(!isAttacked(i, j)){ 
                board[i][j] == 1;
                if(nQueen(N - 1))
                    return true;
                board[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
void print(){    
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            cout << board[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n"; 
    }
}
int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            board[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    nQueen(4);
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

Expected o/p should be:

```
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
```

Actual o/p:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you do know that `true` and `false` are of type `bool` and not `int`?

Comment: Since `board` is global, the entries were already initialized to 0.  So writing a loop to initialize really didn't do anything in terms of initializing the elements to 0.  Also, stay away from one-letter variable names, as `l` and `1` look visually the same, making this harder to debug.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yup! kinda forgot about it!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what should I do to overcome this?

Comment: You should be using a debugger, stepping line-by-line in your code and see where the code deviates from what you expected it to do.  Asking questions such as "*What could be the logical error?*" are not looked on too highly here, unless you showed an effort (by using a debugger) to determine where the issue lies in your code.  **How** to fix the issue is a different question, but you should be taking the initial step identifying *where* the problem is.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie has a good point, you can use an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) such as Visual Studio or CLion(my favorite for easy set up) to help you with debugging.

Comment: @Enthus3d I think I should start using Visual Studio from now on. Btw is there any doc or something I could refer to for learning to debug for Visual Studio(or any other resource that can help me with debugging)? Any good resource that is not specific only to Visual Studio

Comment: @ibrabbit VS is also a good choice :). I think debugging-wise, the most important resource to learn is how to debug :P. You can then apply this to any of your code, not just the VS environment. Let me scrounge up some resources for you and comment them here.

Comment: @Enthus3d that would be very nice of you.

Comment: @ibrabbit I've found a resource by our very own Jon Skeet himself [here](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/debugging.html). He gives a lot of general advice about debugging that you can apply to any language. I also found you a [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/debugging-tips-and-tricks-for-c-in-visual-studio/) for visual studio debugging tools (which are quite useful). Hope that helps! :)

Comment: @Enthus3d thanks bro! I am gonna go home and imma read the article

Comment: @ibrabbit no problem :). By the way, if you end up solving the problem by yourself, you can post the solution and accept it so other people  know you’ve resolve it :P

Comment: @Enthus3d how can I do that? By posting code in comments or via any other way

Comment: @ibrabbit you can just post your own answer and mark it as the answer if you end up solving it by yourself.

Comment: Although I wouldn't do that unless there are no other good answers provided in a short time frame

Comment: @Enthus3d yeah! Definitely

Comment: @ibrabbit: Before writing an elaborate self-answer, you should know that once someone does (break down and) say what’s wrong, this question is probably going to be closed.

Comment: Incidentally, your compiler has warnings.  Turn them on and read them (even though they’re not *all* good).

Comment: @DavisHerring if you are my question on *what could be the logical error* as a self answer, then I am very sorry. And my compiler has given me no warning.

Comment: @ibrabbit: If that’s true, get a [better compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VFcU5V7Oxks12sL8).

Comment: @DavisHerring I was using Visual Code, and there was no warning. Strange! And I don't know how that happened(compiler giving no warnings).

Answer (score 0):

So, I have debugged my code, and it was such a silly mistake :( The mistake was using `==` operator instead of `=` operator inside `nQueen()`.
It should be

```
for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if(!isAttacked(i, j) && (board[i][j] != 1)){ 
                *board[i][j] = 1;*
                if(nQueen(N - 1))
                    return true;
```

instead of

```
for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if(!isAttacked(i, j) && (board[i][j] != 1)){ 
                *board[i][j] == 1;*
                if(nQueen(N - 1))
                    return true;
```

Here is the debugged code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int board[4][4];
int isAttacked(int i, int j){
    for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
        if(board[i][k] == 1 || board[k][j] == 1) return 1; // checking for the rows and columns 
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
        for(int l = 0; l < 4; l++){
            if(((k + l) == (i + j)) || ((k - l) == (i - j))){   // checking for the diagonals 
                if(board[k][l] == 1) 
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
bool nQueen(int N){
    if(N == 0) return true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            if(!isAttacked(i, j) && (board[i][j] != 1)){ 
                board[i][j] = 1;
                if(nQueen(N - 1))
                    return true;
                board[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
void print(){    
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            cout << board[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n"; 
    }
}
int main(){
    nQueen(4);
    print();
    return 0;
}
```